# Store 1000 Preset Words?

Tags: objective-c, macos, ipad

I am developing an iPad/Mac app and need to store 1000 preset words. These words must always be stored, cannot be changed. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store them in a [property list](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html) which you load into an array. You will almost definitely want to change or localise the list at some point in the future, and this is the easiest way of doing that.